Jetpack Compose NavController with same route on multiple navigation graph
I've this situation:
Single NavHost and single NavController with this structure:
NavHost(initialRoute = "A"){
    navigation(route = "A", initialRoute = "A1") {
        composable(route = "A1") {...}
        composable(route = "A2") { // This one
            ScreenA2()
        }
    }
    navigation(route = "B", initialRoute = "B1") {
        composable(route = "B1") {...}
        composable(route = "B2") {...}
        composable(route = "A2") { // This one
            ScreenA2()
        }
    }
}

Graphs "A" and "B" represents two tabs in my application.
At tab switch, I navigate to routes "A" or "B", saving and resuming the states to create independents virtual backstacks for each tab.
In my case, I NEED to have the route "A2" in both graph, so I can navigate to A2 from each graph and maintain separate stacks.
The question is: How can I tell to navigate() function to prefer the "A2" screen within the current navigation graph?
Examples:

I'm in "B1" route and navigating to "A2" the navController should
choose the "B/A2" destination.
I'm in "A1" route and navigating to "A2" the navController should choose the "A/A2" destination.

How can I achieve that?
Answer:
As mentioned by @ianhanniballake in the question's comment, this exactly behavior will be available with the update 2.8.0-beta07 of the navigation lib.

Now when we search for navigate target, instead of starting from base graph, we start from the closest parent NavGraph of current destination. This ensures that when navigating to shared/duplicated destinations, the one closest to the current destination will be prioritized.

From the issue

Did you see this issue that is already planned to be part of Navigation 2.8.0-beta07?

Oh, nice! I searched for hours, but that issue escaped my sight. Exactly what i need, thanks!
